# Validate Form not working - form and validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

```js
$(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
        var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var ans = true;
        var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
        if(first_name === ""){
            window.alert("لا يمكنك ترك خانةالاسم فارغة");
            $("#first_name").addClass("WrongInp");
            ans = false;
        }else{
            $("#first_name").removeClass("WrongInp");
        }
        if(last_name === ""){
            window.alert("لا يمكنك ترك خانةاسم العائلة فارغة");
            $("#last_name").addClass("WrongInp");
            ans = false;
        }else{
            $("#last_name").removeClass("WrongInp");
        }
        if(phone.value === ""){
            window.alert("لا يمكنك ترك خانةالهاتف فارغة");
            $("#phone").addClass("WrongInp");
            ans = false;
        }else{
            $("#phone").removeClass("WrongInp");
        }
        if(phone.length < 9 || phone.length > 14){
            window.alert("ادخل رقم هاتف صحيح");
            $("#phone").addClass("WrongInp");
            ans = false;
        }else{
            $("#phone").removeClass("WrongInp");
        }
        if (email === '') {
           alert('الرجاء ادخال البريد الالكتروني');
           return false;
            }
        if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {
           alert("البريد الالكتروني غير صحيح");
           return false;
            }
        if(ans === true){   
            var url = 'Cant Reveal';
            var form = new FormData();
            form.append("first_name", $('#first_name').val());
            form.append("last_name", $('#last_name').val());
            form.append("phone", $('#phone').val());
            form.append("email", $('#email').val());
            form.append("status", "new");
        
            var settings = {
              "url": "cant Reveal",
              "method": "POST",
              "timeout": 0,
              "headers": {
                "Authorization": "Cant Reveal"
              },
              "processData": false,
              "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
              "contentType": false,
              "data": form
            };
        
            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
              window.location.href = "www.google.com";
            });

        }
    
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
              <input name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" type="text" placeholder="الاسم الكامل" required />
              <input name="phone" id="phone" minlength="8" maxlength="15" class="input" type="text" placeholder="الجوال" required />
              <input name="email" id="email" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}" class="input" type="text" placeholder="البريد الالكتروني" required />
            <button type="text" class="submit">submit</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="LN">
        </form>
```

what is wrong with my code I change something in the javascript section and can't get it back working again!

i think i made changes in the javascript,
first i validate the form and then i submit it with ans
ans must be true
and if one of the fields empty or phone and email doesnt match my validation if goes to false and do not continue

any suggestions to make in javascript section
or maybe i can delete this section and write another better one ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click` handler does not work because you bind it to the HTML element with the id `submit` - `$("#submit")`.

In the provided HTML you're using a class `submit`, not the id.

```
<button type="text" class="submit">submit</button>
```

To make a handler work change this line:

```js
$("#submit").click(function(){
```

to this one

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
```

---

Another option is to use id instead of class in the HTML

```
<button type="text" id="submit">submit</button>
```

---

> any suggestions to make in javascript section or maybe i can delete this section and write another better one ....

If you are a beginner, it's completely ok to have it like this. If you want to make it a bit cleaner *(since you're using jQuery)*, I'd suggest you take a look at the plugin like - [jquery-validation](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation)

Comment: that's awesome , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. Your event handler wasn't attached to your button.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
        var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var ans = true;
        var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
        if(first_name === ""){
            window.alert("لا يمكنك ترك خانةالاسم فارغة");
            $("#first_name").addClass("WrongInp");
            ans = false;
        }else{
            $("#first_name").removeClass("WrongInp");
        }
        if(last_name === ""){
            window.alert("لا يمكنك ترك خانةاسم العائلة فارغة");
            $("#last_name").addClass("WrongInp");
            ans = false;
        }else{
            $("#last_name").removeClass("WrongInp");
        }
        if(phone.value === ""){
            window.alert("لا يمكنك ترك خانةالهاتف فارغة");
            $("#phone").addClass("WrongInp");
            ans = false;
        }else{
            $("#phone").removeClass("WrongInp");
        }
        if(phone.length < 9 || phone.length > 14){
            window.alert("ادخل رقم هاتف صحيح");
            $("#phone").addClass("WrongInp");
            ans = false;
        }else{
            $("#phone").removeClass("WrongInp");
        }
        if (email === '') {
           alert('الرجاء ادخال البريد الالكتروني');
           return false;
            }
        if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {
           alert("البريد الالكتروني غير صحيح");
           return false;
            }
        if(ans === true){   
            var url = 'Cant Reveal';
            var form = new FormData();
            form.append("first_name", $('#first_name').val());
            form.append("last_name", $('#last_name').val());
            form.append("phone", $('#phone').val());
            form.append("email", $('#email').val());
            form.append("status", "new");
        
            var settings = {
              "url": "cant Reveal",
              "method": "POST",
              "timeout": 0,
              "headers": {
                "Authorization": "Cant Reveal"
              },
              "processData": false,
              "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
              "contentType": false,
              "data": form
            };
        
            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
              window.location.href = "www.google.com";
            });

        }
    
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
              <input name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" type="text" placeholder="الاسم الكامل" required />
              <input name="phone" id="phone" minlength="8" maxlength="15" class="input" type="text" placeholder="الجوال" required />
              <input name="email" id="email" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}" class="input" type="text" placeholder="البريد الالكتروني" required />
            <button type="text" class="submit">submit</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="LN">
        </form>
```